# How to set dimensions of the post thumbnails (featured images)

Tags: theme-development, images, post-thumbnails, html

How do I control the dimension for post thumbnails (featured images) on the homepage (blog) of my site?

Dimension for the post thumbnails need to consistently be 470px x 370px. I have tried adjusting the dimension in `Settings > Media` but this does not work.

**My code:**

```
     <div class="posts__post">

        <article>
             // post thumbnail in question
             <a class="posts__post--preview" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></a>
             <p class="posts__post--tag"><?php the_category('&nbsp;/&nbsp;'); ?></p>
             <h1 class="posts__post--title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>
             <p class="posts__post--meta"><?php echo time_ago(); ?></p>
        </article>   

     </div>
```

I initially imported posts via the [Codex theme unit test page](https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Unit_Test) and enabled featured images within my `function.php file`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this code to your theme's `functions.php` file. Images are resized by WordPress when they are uploaded. A plugin such as [Regenerate Thumbnails](https://wordpress.org/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/) can be used to ensure that source images have been properly generated if image sizes are changed after the initial upload.

```
// Sets the parameters for the post-thumbnail image size
// https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/set_post_thumbnail_size
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'wpse239844_image_sizes' );
function wpse239844_image_sizes() {
    set_post_thumbnail_size( 470, 370, true ); // $width, $height, $crop
}
```

Comment: I added the above exact code to my `function.php` and added the regenerate thumbnail plugin but still no luck. What are these values `after_setup_theme', 'wpse239844_image_sizes` Not sure how to approach this as im pretty new to WP

Comment: Did you run the Regenerate Thumbnails plugin under Tools > Regen. Thumbnails? `add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'wpse239844_image_sizes' );` tells WordPress to fire this code at the appropriate time. https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API

Comment: Oh crap I missed that part. it seems to have worked where feature images are appearing at the same size consistently though not at the size initially set 470px by 370px. Not too sure.

Comment: I've tested it, and it works for me. Keep in mind that images must be at least 470x370 for consistent results. Please add more details, such as the original image size, and the image size you are seeing in the browser if you aren't seeing the expected results.

Comment: I see. I'm adding large images (1600 x 1600 ) in the hope that I can use a larger version of that thumbnail for the actual post.  So small thumbnail on the homepage and large version of the post page.  The thumbnail size i am getting right now is 447x367.

Comment: Does your theme have support for [`post thumbnails`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_theme_support/#post-thumbnails)? If not, set the thumbnail size under Settings > Media to 470 x 370 with crop and regenerate thumbnails again.